# How to aggregate boolean column

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I aggregate some tuples like this

```
COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 | COL_4
 val  |   T   |   F   |   F
 val  |   F   |   T   |   F
```

with the OR function and return the following table?

```
COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 | COL_4
 val  |   T   |   T   |   F
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Simply do a `GROUP BY`, use `MAX()` to return T if available, else F.

```
select col_1, max(col_2), max(col_3), max(col_4)
from tablename
group by col_1
```

Comment: This works if you keep a boolean as a string in Postgres, however a `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` will appear if you use a native boolean column. In this case, you should use a `bool_or` as another answer suggests.

Comment: @philpirozhkov, the sample data looks like char(1) columns with T or F as values. Since T > F, the query will work as expected. OP is using Oracle so why should I  use Postgres specific functions? BTW, ANSI SQL specifies TRUE > FALSE.

Comment: Mysql / Mariadb also have BIT_AND and BIT_OR aggregate functions which you can apply to columns of boolean values.  Postgres has BOOL_AND and BOOL_OR.  I think it would give the same result as this suggestion of using MIN or MAX function, but arguably easier to understand the intention.

Answer (score 42):

Just as a side note (doesn't work with Oracle): In PostgreSQL, you would do this:

```
SELECT col_1, bool_or(col_2), bool_or(col_3), bool_or(col_4)
FROM tablename GROUP BY col_1 ORDER BY col_1
```

Answer (score 4):

If `COL_2` to `COL_4` are text columns (`char`, `varchar`, `varchar2`, `nvarchar`, `nvarchar2`) containing `'T'` or `'F'`, then you can just take the `MAX` of them, since `'T' > 'F'`, i.e. `'T'` comes after `'F'` in lexical order.

```
SELECT COL_1, MAX(COL_2) AS COL_2, MAX(COL_3) AS COL_3, MAX(COL_4) AS COL_4
FROM table
GROUP BY COL_1
```

Explanation: The locical operation OR returns TRUE, if at least one of the operands is TRUE. MAX() returns `"T"` if at least one value is `"T"` and otherwise `"F"`.

---

Note: If the Boolean columns were declared as

```
COL_x NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

or any other numeric type then I would take `MAX(ABS(col_x))`, since a negative value counts as TRUE as well. (If you have an Access frontend with a ComboBox attached to a Boolean, it yields the values `0` or `-1`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col1 = MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, ISNULL(col1,0))) ...
```

Explanation:
(S)He's first taking the boolean in col1, or false if null. That gets converted into a TINYINT data type instead of BIT, which may then use the MAX() aggregate function which effectively says "if any are true, return true" in your GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try this:

```
declare @tempTable table(bitval bit)
insert into @tempTable values(1)
insert into @tempTable values(1)
insert into @tempTable values(0)
insert into @tempTable values(1)

select min(cast(bitval as int)) as AndAggregate from @tempTable 
select max(cast(bitval as int)) as ORAggregate from @tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

For Amazon Redshift, the `bool_or` function works.

```sql
WITH b AS (
    SELECT FALSE AS a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TRUE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FALSE
)
SELECT bool_or(a)
FROM b;
-- TRUE

WITH b AS (
    SELECT FALSE AS a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FALSE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FALSE
)
SELECT bool_or(a)
FROM b;
-- FALSE
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_BOOL_OR.html

Answer (score 0):

**using basics of sql**

```
SELECT tt.COL_1,
CASE when tt.COL_2==1 then T else F end AS COL_2,

CASE when tt.COL_3==1 then T else F end AS COL_3,

CASE when tt.COL_4==1 then T else F end AS COL_4,
FROM 
(SELECT COL_1,
MAX( case when COL_2==T then 1 else 0 end) as COL_2,
MAX( case when COL_3==T then 1 else 0 end) as COL_3,
MAX( case when COL_4==T then 1 else 0 end) as COL_4
FROM table GROUP BY COL_1 )as tt
```