# MSSQL SELECT -get one result per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't figure how to write a mssql select to solve this.

Example of a existing table data:

```
Id      GroupID     Pass
___     ________    _____
1       1           1
2       1           0
3       2           1
4       2           0
5       2           0
6       3           1
7       3           1
```

What i need is the following example (if one of Group is not passed, then 0 else 1):

```
GroupID       Pass
________      _____
1             0
2             0
3             1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried a MIN() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MIN aggregation

```
SELECT groupid, MIN(pass)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY groupid
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I think you get your answer why min will work here, so downvote was not applicable in this case

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, if one of Group is not passed, min(pass) will be equals to 0. Otherwise, 1. It does not fullfil the requirement? Also it seems to be a dupplicate of  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37947668/4375327).

Comment: what do you mean by one group? @Amessihel

Comment: Sorry,I missed that.  This would work for the actual data, because there are no other columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, no worries, sometimes it heppens :)

Comment: @Amessihel - ok

Comment: Thank you! That's what i want :)

Answer (score 1):

use window function `row_number()`

```
select GroupID,Pass from (
    select *, 
    row_number() over(
        partition by GroupID 
        order by Pass asc
     ) as [rn] 
    from [yourtable] as [t]
) as [t1]
where [rn] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`MIN`** function with **`GROUP BY`**.

**Query**

```
select [GroupID], min([Pass]) as [Pass]
from [your_table_name]
group by [GroupID]
order by [GroupID];
```

And if the `Pass` column is in `BIT` type, then need to cast in to `INT`.

Comment: `if one of Group is not passed, then 0 else 1` ... you missed this requirement

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Per `GroupId`, if any row have `0` as `Pass` value, then it takes `0`. If all values are `1` then it takes `1`. And if all values are `0` then it takes `0`. So `MIN()` should work.